# Got TimeoutException when try to download file from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, blob, reactive

Im trying to download file from Azure blob storage with flowing code:

```
blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString)
                    .buildClient();
BlobClient b = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(remotePath);
b.downloadToFile(localPath, true);
```

But sometimes i got this exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 60000ms in 'map' (and no fallback has been configured)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:288)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.doTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:273)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutTimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:390)
    at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onNext(StrictSubscriber.java:89)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:117)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:50)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:27)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Do we have any solution to make it's stable?
Version:

```
        <azure-storage-blob.version>12.6.0</azure-storage-blob.version>
        <azure-core.version>1.3.0</azure-core.version>
```

Comment: How big is the file that you're trying to download? What's your Internet connection speed?

Comment: File size upto 50GB and i was trying with the bad internet

Comment: Can you share the complete code especially the code to create service client?

Comment: just added my code

Comment: HI @GauravMantri do you have any idea ?

Comment: I was trying to look a property that would dictate how many bytes can be downloaded in a single request but unfortunately I was not able to find it. I believe you will need to use `downloadStreamWithResponse` method and specify the byte ranges you want to download and create the file manually using these chunks.

Comment: Here's the link to that method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blobclientbase.downloadstreamwithresponse?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_storage_blob_specialized_BlobClientBase_downloadStreamWithResponse_java_io_OutputStream_com_azure_storage_blob_models_BlobRange_com_azure_storage_blob_models_DownloadRetryOptions_com_azure_storage_blob_models_BlobRequestConditions_boolean_java_time_Duration_com_azure_core_util_Context_. HTH.

Comment: you mean azure SDK can not download the large file and we have to handel it manualy

Comment: SDK can download the large files however considering you are trying to download large files over a slow Internet connection, using `downloadToFile` may not work. That's why I am recommending using `downloadStreamWithResponse` as it will give you more freedom.

Comment: Cause I'm using Blob version 12.6.0 and don't have that function.
Do we have any options to touch on timeout value?

Comment: Can you share a link to the SDK documentation for version 12.6.0 and I will try to find appropriate method. I remember seeing an option for setting the timeout value but the maximum timeout limit is 90 seconds for each REST operation so I don't think that would be of much help.

Comment: Here is the document: https://javadoc.io/doc/com.azure/azure-storage-blob/12.6.0/index.html. I try to set the retry value to 4 in Downloadoptions but now we got SSLHandshake timeout.

Comment: Please try to use [`downloadToFileWithResponse `](https://javadoc.io/static/com.azure/azure-storage-blob/12.6.0/com/azure/storage/blob/specialized/BlobClientBase.html#downloadToFileWithResponse-java.lang.String-com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobRange-com.azure.storage.blob.models.ParallelTransferOptions-com.azure.storage.blob.models.DownloadRetryOptions-com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobRequestConditions-boolean-java.time.Duration-com.azure.core.util.Context-). You can tweak the download settings using `ParallelTransferOptions`. HTH.

Comment: I just realize that issue happened in k8s only. With 5gb file and chunk size is 0.5mbs it take 30secons but if chunk size is 1mb we got time out